# Visualizing an RNN/LSTM

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I am new to Recurrent Neural Network and LSTMs. I have a good idea of they work and the training procedure. But I am having a hard time visualizing them, especially after reading the Tensorflow docs and also understanding the related terminologies. While building LSTMs, are all the Hidden layer units an LSTM cell? I mean if I have 100 units in a hidden layer, does it mean that there are 100 LSTM cells?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> While building LSTMs, are all the Hidden layer units an LSTM cell?

No.

> I mean if I have 100 units in a hidden layer, does it mean that there are 100 LSTM cells?

No.

I don't even know what to say more. I recommend reading [Understanding LSTM Networks](http://colah.github.io/posts/2015-08-Understanding-LSTMs/).

I would say [this code](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/examples/lstm_text_generation.py#L51-L56) has one LSTM layer with 128 units. One LSTM unit consists of multiple nodes.